# count the number of values returned by regex extractor in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

How do I count the number of samples/values returned by jmeter extractors.

I am using regex to get the list of links to a variable using regex extractor. 
By debug sampler shows that there many values returned. until like 9_g1

```
PlanLinksArray_9_g=1
PlanLinksArray_9_g0=/hix/admin/planmgmt/viewqhpdetail/gLe8eM5psNUTqo8aYXo20w
PlanLinksArray_9_g1=/hix/admin/planmgmt/viewqhpdetail/gLe8eM5psNUTqo8aYXo20w
```

How can i get the count of this to a variable in Jmeter??

Answer (score 0):

AS per:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors

it will be called:

> PlanLinksArray_9_matchNr : the number of matches found; could be 0

Answer (score 0):

You can get extracted variables count as `${PlanLinksArray_matchNr}` it will hold the number of variables like:

```
PlanLinksArray_1
PlanLinksArray_2
PlanLinksArray_3
etc.
```

If you need to include match groups as well, like

```
PlanLinksArray_1_g
PlanLinksArray_1_g0
PlanLinksArray_1_g1
etc.
```

you'll have to do some scripting.

1. Add a [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) after your Regular Expression extractor
2. Put the following code into the PostProcessor's "Script" area

   ```
   JMeterVariables vars = new JMeterVariables();
   Iterator iterator = vars.getIterator();
   int counter = 0;
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
       Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
       if (e.getKey().startsWith("PlanLinksArray")) {
           counter++;
       }
   }

   vars.put("extractedValues", String.valueOf(counter));
   ```
3. Number of variables which names start with "PlanLinksArray" will be available as  `${extractedValues}` variable

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more Beanshell tips and tricks.